# How to using logoff button in mdi form

Tags: vb.net

I am using logoff button as click then mdi form need to close and then login page should appear

Comment: What are the names of the mdi form and the login form? Do you want help in writing code to open the login form when the MDI form close event is fired?

Comment: my mdi form name is mobileMDI and login form name is Login

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In mobileMDI add this code:

```
Public Class modileMDI

    Private Sub btnLogoff_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnLogoff.Click
        Login.Show()
        Me.Hide()
    End Sub
End Class
```

I assume the logoff button is named btnLogoff.